# Get values from a nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given this array I'm getting from an XHR request:

```
[
 {
  "dinnerID": "h1799-05-20a",
  "date": "20 May 1799",
  "note": "<note xmlns=\"http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0\"/>",
  "diners": {
    "name": [
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Miss Caroline Fox"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Lady Lucy Anne FitzGerald"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Dr ??? Drew"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Lady Elizabeth Vassall-Fox"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Lord Richard Vassall-Fox"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
 }
 {
  "dinnerID": "h1799-05-21a",
  "date": "21 May 1799",

 }
]
```

how do I get a list of the names (`person`), and also use the other `mentioend`, `slept`, and `cancelled`?

This:

```
for (var dinner of result) {
                    
    let diners = dinner.diners.name.person.join(", ")
}
```

returns a `Uncaught TypeError: dinner.diners.name.person is undefined` error. I'd like to return something like

```
Miss Caroline Fox (slept)(mentioned)(cancelled), Lady Lucy Anne FitzGerald (slept)(mentioned)(cancelled) etc.
```

I'm attaching a screenshot of my `console.log(result)`.

[image: console.log]

Comment: That's a single object, not an array. Did you mean you have an array of objects like that?

Comment: `dinner.diners.name` is a 2-dimensional array. You need to loop through it.

Comment: `dinner.diners.name.forEach((name) => name.person)`

Comment: @Woohaik That won't work either. Notice that each object is inside another array.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I meant that I have an array of those objects. I'm editing my question and adding that information.

Comment: Your edit is not an array. An array begins with `[` not `{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplefy the data, we'll get something like

```json
{
  "diners": {
    "name": [
      [
        {
          "mentioned": null,
          "slept": "no",
          "cancelled": null,
          "person": "Miss Caroline Fox"
        }
      ],
      ...
  }
}
```

Here we see that `diners` is an *Object*, holding an array on `name` key.
Since each `diner` is an object, inside an extra array, we'll need to target that aswell.

To get the desire output, use something like;

```js
const result = {"dinnerID": "h1799-05-20a", "date": "20 May 1799", "note": "<note xmlns=\"http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0\"/>", "diners": {"name": [[{"mentioned": null, "slept": "no", "cancelled": null, "person": "Miss Caroline Fox"} ], [{"mentioned": null, "slept": "no", "cancelled": null, "person": "Lady Lucy Anne FitzGerald"} ], [{"mentioned": null, "slept": "no", "cancelled": null, "person": "Dr ??? Drew"} ], [{"mentioned": null, "slept": "no", "cancelled": null, "person": "Lady Elizabeth Vassall-Fox"} ], [{"mentioned": null, "slept": "no", "cancelled": null, "person": "Lord Richard Vassall-Fox"} ] ] } };

const res = result.diners.name.map(diner => {
  let obj = diner[0];
  return `${obj.person} (${obj.slept}) (${obj.mentioned}) (${obj.cancelled})`;
});

console.log(res.join(' '));
```

```
Miss Caroline Fox (no) (null) (null) Lady Lucy Anne FitzGerald (no) (null) (null) Dr ??? Drew (no) (null) (null) Lady Elizabeth Vassall-Fox (no) (null) (null) Lord Richard Vassall-Fox (no) (null) (null)
```

Comment: Thank you @0stone0, excellent. One last question: How can conditionally output (or not) customised strings for the three parameters? Something like ```return `${obj.person} ${obj.slept} == 'yes') ? '(s)' : '' ${obj.mentioned} == 'yes' ? '(m)' : '' ${obj.cancelled} == 'yes' ? '(c)' : ''`;``` outputs literal strings.

Comment: That's fine, I solved with ```return obj.person + (obj.slept == 'yes' ? '(s)' : '') + (obj.mentioned == 'yes' ? '(m)' : '') + (obj.cancelled == 'yes' ? '(c)' : '');```

Answer (score 1):

`dinner.diners.name` is a 2-dimensional array of object. You can flatten it and then map through that to get all the names.

```
result.forEach(dinner => {
    let diners = dinner.diners.name.flat().map(d => d.person).join("");
    console.log(diners);
})
```

Comment: I get a number of <empty string> with this.

Comment: Sorry, `d.name` should have been `d.person`

Comment: True. Interesting approach. I can I also have the slept etc, as per last part of my question?